# To filter a dataframe column with spaces only

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

To filter a dataframe column with spaces only
example:

input dataframe:

```
|col_name |  col_desc |                                         |
|---------|-----------|-----------------------------------------| 
|A        |           |     has a single space character i.e. ' '|
|B        |           |     has 2 consecutive space character i.e. '  '|
|C        |    text   |     starts with space followed by 'text' i.e ' text'|
|D        |           |     has multiple spaces|
```

output:

```
|col_name |  col_desc |                                         |
|---------|-----------|-----------------------------------------| 
|A        |           |     has a single space character i.e. ' '|
|B        |           |     has 2 consecutive space character i.e. '  '|
|D        |           |     has multiple spaces|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the string method [`isspace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isspace):

```
df[df.col_desc.str.isspace()]
```

Note that it won't keep empty strings, though. From docs:

> **str.isspace()**
> Return True if there are only whitespace characters in the string and there is at least one character, False otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to replace all spaces with nothing. If there is nothing remaining, then that is what you want:

```
df[df['col_desc'].str.replace(' ', '') == '']
```

You could also use `\s` or `\s+` to accomplish this. Using `\s+` might be the most efficient, since less overall replaces since capturing consectuive space and replacing all at once:

```
df[df['col_desc'].str.replace('\s+', '') == '']
```

Comment: Thanks David, my requirement is not to replace anything but filter out data as is with null, empty or spaces. Null and empty was easy but need solution for space

Comment: @RanjanaJha, you are not replacing anything, you are *filtering by a new series with replace values*. Does that make sense? In terms of null or Empty, that was not part of your question.